# Combine Two Entities Into One Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to combine my two different entities into one new entity. Here is a sample of my class entity:

```
public class CarOne
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

    }

    public class CarTwo
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }  

    }
```

Now I want to save all my list of two enties into this new entity:

```
public class CarFinal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }  

    }
```

Here is the sample of my code:

```
        CarOne carToyota = new CarOne()
        {
            Name = "Toyota",
            Model = "Camry"
        };

        CarTwo carDetails = new CarTwo()
        {
           Year = 2012,
           Description = "This is a great car"
        };

        List<CarOne> lstFirst = new List<CarOne>();
        lstFirst.Add(carToyota);

        List<CarTwo> lstSecond = new List<CarTwo>();
        lstSecond.Add(carDetails);
```

Now here is what I am trying to do, I am trying to combine these two list which contains same number of elements, in this case, both List contains one number of element. What I have tried so far is:

```
        var result1 = lstFirst.Select(x => new CarFinal
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Model = x.Model
        }).ToList();

        var result2 = lstSecond.Select(x => new CarFinal
        {
            Year = x.Year,
            Description = x.Description
        }).ToList();

        List<CarFinal> lstFinal = new List<CarFinal>();
        lstFinal = result1.Union(result2).ToList();
```

I also tried:

```
        lstFinal = result1.Concat(result2).ToList();
```

But the output of these two methods will both produce two elements, which is I am trying to just combine all properties into one. I am expecting one entity only as result but I am always getting two elements on my combination.

Comment: please read about methods before using them!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Zip` like this:

```
var finalList = lstFirst.Zip(lstSecond, (c1, c2) => new CarFinal()
        {
            Name = c1.Name,
            Model = c1.Model,
            Description = c2.Description,
            Year = c2.Year
        }).ToList();
```